# Is there any good dynamic memory analyzer for C++ apps that runs on AIX OS

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, aix

We have a large multi-threaded app that runs on AIX OS. There is some memory leak in the app but on AIX I could not find any dynamic memory analyzer.

Is there any good dynamic memory analyzer for CPP apps that runs on AIX OS?

I have compiled the code for Linux and used Valgrind. But for Linux, Valgrind report is clean and didn't report any Leak. May be because application has tons of AIX platform specific code with lots of ifdefs.

I also tried malloc debug for AIX, but it's not helping for multi-threaded apps.

Comment: Can you compile and run the application on a Linux box instead of the AIX box?  Then you would be able to use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to check for leaks in the application code — but not so reliably for leaks in the library code (since the libraries on AIX and Linux are different).  There's a good chance that it would find the problem; there's also a chance that it would not find it.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for the suggestion, But i have already tried Valgrind. Valgrind report is clean without any leak. Code has tons of AIX platform specific code with lots of ifdefs with linkage to multiple libraries.

Comment: Add that information to the question so other people won't make the same suggestion.  Do you have an opinion on whether the leak is in your application's code or whether it is in the libraries you use?  And are you sure you're using the library's clean-up code correctly.  In C++, that's harder to get wrong, in general, because of destructors, but funnier things have been known.